# How do I set the first UIViewController's view to autoresize?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` subclass to handle my view for a landscape only application. I'd like for its view to resize to reflect the landscape dimensions automatically, but it doesn't seem to. A subview, however, does.

Here's the reproducing code.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
  UIView *subview;
}

@implementation MyViewController

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:subview];
  }

  return self;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
  NSLog(@"My view's frame (%f,%f)", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
  NSLog(@"Subview's frame (%f,%f)", subview.frame.size.width, subview.frame.size.height);
}

@end
```

And then...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
  self.window.rootViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Super simple. And yet, on boot, it logs:

```
My view's frame (320.000000,480.000000)
Subview's frame (480.000000,320.000000)
```

The subview is resized properly, but the parent view still has a portrait oriented frame.

How do I make the top level view resize to fit the landscape mode?

Answer (score 3):

You have to allow the window autoresize subviews:

```
window.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. select autoresize Subviews on the first view under attributes inspector when not using auto layout.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your viewController

```
self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Add this in your viewdidload . Make sure in storyboard , Viewcontrollers view property is assigned to view

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        //is portrait
    
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)

    
    } else {

       //is landscape

       view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320);
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just hardcodes it in, which is trivial but I'd like to avoid. Even in the current device ecosystem that code would need another branch to check the device idiom, phone or pad.